# how to auto increment variable

Tags: php, mysql

I need some quick help, I need to know if I can somehow increment the $user_id by one so that I do not get a duplicate entry error. Do I just add a +1 after ['user_id']?

```
 public function insert_video($video_id,$user_id,$caption) {
                $userObject = array();
                $userObject['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $userObject['video_id'] = $video_id;
                $userObject['caption'] = str_replace(array("'",'"'), '', $caption);
                $userObject['description'] = '';
                $userObject['votes'] = 0;
                $userObject['upload_time'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $userObject['version'] = $this->contests->contest->version; //4
                //if($this->contests->contest->auto_approve)
                $userObject['approved'] = 1;
                $this->db->insert('photos', $userObject);
                return $this->db->insert_id();
```

ok guys I edited the function and removed any mention of user_id but for some reason I still get the error when I try to submit another video. Should I try dropping that column on the table? here is my updated function

```
public function insert_video($video_id,$caption) {
    $userObject = array();
    //$userObject['user_id'] = $user_id+1;
    $userObject['video_id'] = $video_id;
    $userObject['caption'] = str_replace(array("'",'"'), '', $caption);
    $userObject['description'] = '';
    $userObject['votes'] = 0;
    $userObject['upload_time'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $userObject['version'] = $this->contests->contest->version; //4
    //if($this->contests->contest->auto_approve)
    $userObject['approved'] = 1;
    $this->db->insert('photos', $userObject);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: If `$uder_id` means the actual MAX id, the answer to "Do I just add a +1 after ['user_id']?": **yes**

Comment: Why don't you make it an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in the table definition?

Comment: Usually you can set your mysql column to auto increment, then you leave it out if your insert statement.
However in this case, you're inserting rows for video. Can a user have multiple videos? if so the user id shouldn't be a unique column.

Comment: user_id is already set to auto increment actually but my problem is that then prevents the user from uploading a video again for that same user_id. I keep getting error Duplicate entry '7339-19' for key 'user_id'

INSERT INTO `photos` (`user_id`, `video_id`, `caption`, `description`, `votes`, `upload_time`, `version`, `approved`) VALUES (7339, 'fDTm1IzQf-U', 'new test', '', 0, '2014-11-12 16:17:36', '19', 1)

Comment: is there an easy way to change user_id column so its not unique?

Comment: Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and provide the structure for the table

Comment: Since this is a table for videos, you'll probably want video_id to be the unique auto_increment key. This way a user can have multiple videos. Do you have a separate user table? that would be where you'd want the user_id to be a unique value. @user2777216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up your `user_id` To auto increment. If you find it easier as you clearly have a table already set up, use phpMyAdmin to set the AI tick box to true.

Then when you INSERT, you'll get a unique value. You do not need to specify the `user_id` as that'll be taken care of.

```
INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Matt','HB')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to have 2 tables, one that holds a user info with auto incresment column e.g. "ID".
In table photos don't use auto incresment for user_id, as you need to give users ability to insert multiple photos and update current. just change in your table:

```
  `user_id` to `ID` -> this will auto incresment 
    create new column `user_id` int 200.. this will be a reference of `column - "ID"` from  **userinfo** table;
      //then run your query:
    INSERT INTO photos (user_id, video_id, caption, description, votes, upload_time, version, approved) VALUES (7339, 'fDTm1IzQf-U', 'new test', '', 0, '2014-11-12 16:17:36', '19', 1)
```

Comment: I actually do have another table that holds the user_id information called users. So if I just remove user_id on the insert command for my photos table that would solve my error?

Comment: actually I could probably just drop the user_id column on the photos table correct? since I had it set in another table.

Comment: use user_id in this table as reference to actual unique user_id in your user info table, no need for auto incresment ...

Comment: would you be willing to let me e-mail you some files to see if you can help me out? I have to try and get this fixed by the weekend. My boss wants user to be able to submit unlimited videos.

Comment: please e-mail me at jonvanasco@gmail.com and I will email you the few files I think need to be edited but nothing I have tried works.